# How can I exclude a set of Folders while creating a branch in tortoise svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Currently, my project has a folder structure as below:

```
ProjectName
  ServiceName01
    01Smoke
    02DataVariance
  ServiceName02
    01Smoke
    02DataVariance
..
  ServiceNameNN
    01Smoke
    02DataVariance
```

I want to create a branch of this project excluding all 01Smoke folders and the tests within it as it contains sensitive data which I do not wish to expose. 
How can I achieve this  with Svn?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't do it *easy*
2. You can't do it as `URL-> URL` repository-side copy (because `svn copy` copy the whole tree from BRANCH-ROOT)
3. You have to prepare [sparse Working Copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) locally ([TortoiseSVN-specific instruction](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) for sparse checkout or sparse update /below/) and branch *this* WC

**PS:** Maybe URL-URL will be possible (not tested), if you'll branch (and only branch) as special user, which haven't rights for reading `01Smoke` dirs. Anyway, path-based authorization must be enabled in repo, special user and user-specific rules have to be created by SVN-admin and you must don't forget to clean-up "full user" credentials before branching